# "Properly" dereferencing pointer to address zero in RISC-V

Tags: gcc, riscv, null-pointer, riscv32

I am developing bare metal code for a RV32IMC chip using gcc. I have memory mapped starting from address 0x0. I use simple pointers like `uint32_t *p = 0x0;` to access that address.

I was surprised when gcc compiled my function into a single `ebreak`. It turned out to be [by design](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain/issues/311#issuecomment-359100361).

To access address zero I eventually added `__attribute__((optimize("no-delete-null-pointer-checks")))` to the whole function. **Is that the proper way to access address zero in RISC-V gcc** and avoid getting the code optimized out? Are there better options?

Comment: It looks like this gcc option was added specifically to address this issue, so it's probably OK to use it.