Function pointer is always zero, but works when dereferenced and called
Here is a minimal example of code I have (I've tried running the minimal example to make sure it reproduces the issue I'm seeing):
void testfn(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("fp: %p\n", &testfn);
    return 0;
}

The output I get is fp: 0x0000000000000000, indicating that the function pointer I'm trying to print is 0. I've tried using the GCC __attribute__((noinline)) attribute on testfn() and I get the same result.
I am compiling for a RISC-V system and running in QEMU. I thought that perhaps the printf() implementation was buggy (though it looks good to me and other pointers print just fine), so I tried casting the function pointer to an unsigned 64-bit int and then looping that many iterations (I recognize this is technically UB, but usually works in practice and this is a dumb test), but the loop performs precisely 0 iterations:
void __attribute__((noinline)) testfn(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    void (*fn)(void) = &testfn;

    printf("Testing printf...\n");
    printf("fp addr: %p\n", &fn);
    fn();

    for (int i = 0; i < (unsigned long long) fn; ++i) {
        printf("Here!\n");
    }

    printf("fp: %p\n", fn);
    return 0;
}

This produces the following output:
Testing printf...
fp addr: 0x0000000000003FA8
Hello, world!
fp: 0x0000000000000000

Here is the command being used for compilation: riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -Wall -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -ggdb -gdwarf-2 -MD -mcmodel=medany -ffreestanding -fno-common -nostdlib -mno-relax -I. -fno-stack-protector -fno-pie -no-pie -c -o user/rkttest.o user/rkttest.c
Here is the command I'm using to run QEMU; qemu-system-riscv64 -machine virt -bios none -kernel kernel/kernel -m 128M -smp 3 -nographic -global virtio-mmio.force-legacy=false -drive file=fs.img,if=none,format=raw,id=x0 -device virtio-blk-device,drive=x0,bus=virtio-mmio-bus.0.
It seems to me that the function pointer is always zero, except when I try to call it as a function. This feels to me like a compiler bug or some weird thing happening in my environment, but I thought I'd throw it up here on Stack Overflow. Am I missing something?

What happens if you use printf("fp: %p\n", (void *) &testfn);? The %p conversion is specified to take a void *, not any other type of pointer.

@EricPostpischil Are pointers to functions really convertible to void *?

@Someprogrammerdude: Yes. The C standard does not define the conversion, but it does not stop you from doing it.

Note that testfn and &testfn are the same in both value and type.

Good thought. I tried casting to (void *) with no change in output or behavior.

@tedtanner, Try printf("fp: %jX\n", (uintmax_t) &testfn); as void * may be too narrow for a function pointer.  Also, let us find the function pointer size with printf("%zu\n", sizeof(&testfn));

This could be because you build for some kind of embedded system. If you build for your PC, do you get the same result?

If you build for some embedded system, a check with the map file might reveal what you have to expect.

RISC-V can apparently read-protect executable pages. Maybe that's what's going on here?

It appears the system is literally placing the code section at address 0x0 and the compiler is putting the function at the beginning of the code section. This is a REALLY bad idea on part of the system. Nothing should be at address 0x0, ever.
The following code:
static void __attribute__((noinline)) testfn(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

static void __attribute__((noinline)) testfn2(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("fp: %p\n", (void *) &testfn);
    printf("fp: %p\n", (void *) &testfn2);

    return 0;
}

produces the following output:
fp: 0x000000000000001A
fp: 0x0000000000000000

Oh boy. ‍♂️
Edit: Okay, maybe saying "nothing should be at address 0x0, ever" isn't necessarily true (counterpoint: systems without virtual addressing). But for systems with virtual addressing, I still believe it is a really bad idea to map that page, if only to avoid issues arising from bad assumptions.

Curious as to what this will print:  void *p = NULL; unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)&p; for (int i;i<sizeof(void*); i++) printf("%02x ", c[i]);.  I suspect it may not be all zeros.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77321435/properly-dereferencing-pointer-to-address-zero-in-risc-v

@dbush printing out memory at address zero gives non-zero values

Not memory at address zero, the representation of a NULL pointer.

The null pointer prints out as 0x0000000000000000 when I print it with %p. The implementation of printf on the system is basic and doesn't support %02x.

tedtanner, %p expects a void *.  &testfn is not a void *, so printf("fp: %p\n", &testfn); has undefined behavior (UB).  So this answer's conclusions are not well supported. printf("fp: %p\n", (void *) &testfn); is better, yet that may truncate the function pointer (which may be wider than a void *).  First let us find the size of a function pointer with printf("%zu\n", sizeof(&testfn)); or printf("%u\n", (unsigned) sizeof(&testfn));. AFAIK, a function pointer may be 128-bit here - which would explain your troubles.

The "zero page" (the first section of the memory) is commonly used for for different things. It's not uncommon for some small embedded systems to start execution at that address. Or to keep an interrupt table or other system-dependent data at address 0.

Also note that NULL doesn't have to be equal to 0. Historically there have been systems where that were the case.

What's the value if you declare a function pointer and print its raw value with something like void (*fnPtr)(void) = testfn; unsigned char rawPtrValue[sizeof(fnPtr)]; memcpy(rawPtrValue, &fnPtr, sizeof(rawPtrValue));?  That should avoid any possible translations from a function address to a void *, and you'll be able to see the size of a function pointer.


Nothing should be at address 0x0, ever.. Why a chunk of address space (at least one byte) must be wasted just because some language use 0 as a special value for pointer? Not all architectures have address virtualization.


@chux-ReinstateMonica Excellent thoughts. However, casing to a void * still shows zero. The pointer is not being truncated; the function pointer is not wider that a void * on this system. I have found the issue in the system (it was a rather difficult fix) that caused the code section to be mapped to virtual address 0x0 in the process's page table, so I do have enough to support this conclusion. You are correct, however, that my answer posted here does not necessarily prove what I am trying to prove.

@Someprogrammerdude That is good to know. I've generally steered away from mapping that first page because many programmers rely on that being unmapped, but you're right that it doesn't necessarily need to be that way. I still think it is a bad idea to map that page. Also, good luck explaining to the Germans that null doesn't have to be 0 xD

@dimich Only a Sith deals in absolutes, and apparently I am a Sith. Without address virtualization, I would likely back off of my statement. My opinion is that in systems with address virtualization, because many programmers assume 0 is unmapped, one shouldn't map that page to avoid issues arising from bad assumptions.

@tedtanner To map, or not to map - it's a choice of OS, not a hardware neither a language.

@tedtanner Please consider adding the result of printf("%u %d %p\n", (unsigned) sizeof &testfn2, &testfn2 == NULL, (void *) NULL);.
